# Shortened URLs. Expand multiple trimmed links?

Tags: php

Sure, there are many services out there which offer the service of expanding shortened links. But all of them don't provide any solid way of expanding multiple links at once.

I want to expand all the t.co URLs in this page: http://davidhiggins.me/tweets/

Is there any PHP class I can use to do this?

Comment: What is "expand" in this context? You mean to get the URL the t.co link redirects to?

Answer (score 0):

Just get all the links in the format with REGEX, and then make separate requests to determine which page they redirect to.

Unfortunately, there is no other solution (less requests). Regex used to capture all the links would look like this:

```
http://t.co/(.+?)\s
```